# Manager is becoming increasingly forgetful. How should I deal with this?

Tags: manager

Lately my manager has been increasingly forgetful in a way I've never witnessed before. He always forgets what he's been told and in the next day he deals with it as if it's a brand new discussion, which damages our workflow as a team.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: Put everything in writing.

Comment: And even if he remember things, having writing trace is always better :D

Comment: I can't add to Bugs' comment, but a sudden sharp rise in forgetfulness could be some form of illness

Comment: @Cursed1701 or simply stress

Comment: If you start to forget things to that extend, then it aint "simply" stress. Could be stress, but nothing simple about it.

Comment: Ask him to watch the movie Memento. He can carry notes around and important notes can be tattooed on the body. :)

Comment: Are you asking for ways to work around this or for a way to bring this up with your manager? Whether the latter is worth trying is something only you can really answer. We don't know your manager or your relationship with him.

Comment: A sudden change in any mental ability is a major red flag health wise.  Have you made them aware of this change?

Answer (score 12):

Write him emails for each subject and also follow up with notes from the discussions you had where decisions were made.  Make a comment in the email that you are recording the conversation main points so that you can remember it later and references it.  This gets you in the habit of making a paper trail for all your direction as well as writing it down and keeping in sync with others in writing as well.  It helps everyone to have a written paper trail as noone can remember everything.  At the same time it will also remind him of previous discussions.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.  Email paper trail along with responses.  This should be of help to the MGR too.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a company two years ago, with a good method for that.

We had a huge white board with columns saying :

- Secondary objectives
- Important objectives
- In progress
- Done

The idea is that all the tasks in progress are still conserved in a physical way, allowing you and your forgetful manager to know what's up in the team very fast and whenever it's needed.

There are a lot of ways to have traces of the work done, needed and the troubles, an excel for example, or a Trello or an IT Ticket system.

Comment: +1 This is a great answer because it is an aide-memoire for *everyone*